# Will Skyrim Run On Windows 8?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I posted a related question about my situation on SU. [Here is the link](https://superuser.com/questions/567350/windows-7-oem-64-bit-installation)

I am trying to upgrade my 32 bit Home Basic Win 7 edition to 64 bit since I added some more RAM. And it is looking like I can not download any 64 bit sources from Microsoft's Digital River service. They are only offering Windows 8 download sources these days.

I would like to know if I can not upgrade my 32 bit installation to 64 bit, instead of purchasing a Win 7 64 bit disc from the market, I would rather purchase a 64 bit Win 8 disc.

But will Skyrim run on Windows 8 without any problems?

Comment: There's no problem being solved here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you consider Windows 8 itself a problem, Skyrim runs fine in Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 and 8 aren't that far away when it comes to compatibility. I've seen multiple people play Skyrim without problems(none that they complained about, anyway). I think you would be fine doing that.